# What is this inversion called, and is it formal or normal?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative, niveau-de-langue, inversion

There's a certain type of interrogative phrasing I often stumble over, which I have always called *complex inversion* but which I am not sure of the real name for. I don't know why I thought it was called that. Here are examples:

> Le chien a-t-il mangé aujourd'hui?
>   Où votre père travaille-t-il?
>   Comment Madame Thatcher est-elle devenue premier ministre?

These are examples of questions that use inversion with a redundant subject pronoun, which is what I'm talking about, and I always have some trouble knowing when to use this.

Is this type of phrasing somewhat formal? Is there a more natural way to phrase these questions without using inversion? Would using *est-ce que* seem more familliar / natural, or is it about the same? I seem to see this phrasing more often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs formes pour l'interrogatif. La deuxième est la plus facile à construire et fonctionne toujours.

**Entendez-vous ?** (inversion verbe-pronom sujet)

**Est-ce que vous m'entendez ?** (forme est-ce que + forme affirmative, forme très usitée passe-partout)

**Vous m'entendez ?** (forme tolérée mais très usitée à l'oral)

**Le garçon mange-t-il sa soupe ?** (ajout et inversion verbe-pronom lorsque le sujet n'est pas un pronom)

**Entends-je ces murmures ?** (forme inversée à la première personne du singulier, peu usitée, et considérée commme snob, les autres personnes s'emploient)

**Le garçon, il mange sa soupe ?** (forme parlée, pour accentuer la question).

**Lorsque la question ne porte pas sur l'affirmation complète comme au-dessus (questions OUI-NON), mais sur les circonstances, on retrouve les mêmes constructions, avec un groupe nominal ou un pronom:**

Tu travailles à l'usine =>

**Où travailles-tu ?** (adverbe interrogatif + inversion avec pronom)

Où travaille Jacques ?

**Où est-ce que tu travailles ?** (adverbe interrogatif + est-ce que + forme affirmative)

Où est-ce que Jacques travaille ?

**Où tu travailles ?** (forme tolérée à l'oral)

Où Jacques travaille ?

**Tu travailles où  ?** (forme tolérée à l'oral)

Jacques travaille où ?

**Tu travailles où ça ?** (forme insistante tolérée à l'oral)

Jacques travaille où ça ?

**Où Jacques travaille-t-il ?** (adverbe interrogatif + sujet long + inversion avec pronom)

Comment: Cette réponse est très complète, mais la dernière forme me semble superflue, car vous n'indiquez pas suffisamment nettement que cette forme est incorrecte, alors qu'elle relève vraiment d'un mauvais niveau de langage: on dirait du François Hollande!

Comment: Are there other ways to ask where Jacques works? *"Où travaille Jacques ?"* par exemple ?

Comment: @Aerovistae , elles sont toutes équivalentes: pronom ou GN. Je les ai rajoutées (sauf la dernière bien sur qui a les 2 à la fois).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because in inversion the subject and verb are switched; however, you can only flip them if they are subject pronouns. If the subject is not a pronoun, you must put the subject "Le chien" and then use its subject pronoun counterpart "il" in this case to invert.

*Wrong:*

> Est-chien grand ?

*Correct:*

> Le chien est-il grand ?

When the subject is included before the inversion, then it would approximately translate (in this case) to

> Is the dog big ?

**NOT**

> The dog is he big?

Basically it specifies the subject being inverted, since non-subject pronouns cannot be inverted.

**Update**

If you use *Est-ce que...*, there is no need to use the subject pronoun.

Orally you will almost always hear questions asked as statements with intonation.

> Le chien est grand ?

This is my personal experience, but it may prove helpful. Except in more formal settings, you really should use intonation in place of inversion as it sounds more casual. *Est-ce que* is ok.

Comment: But is it more natural to say "Le chien est grand?" / "Est-ce que le chien est grand?"

Comment: In spoken French, yes

Comment: Orally you will almost always hear questions asked as statements, but with intonation. Except in more formal settings.

Comment: Which way of asking questions do the French use more often in speech: making statements questions just by using the right intonation or using *est-ce que*?